# Cannot read property 'urls' of undefined after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've created a photo app when the user clicks on the modal then the modal pops up with a new url with the photo id. However, when I refresh the page then it shows the error. I'm using unsplash api to retrieve the photos. how to remove this error when the user refreshes the page and show the modal instead which was there before the refresh?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-rain-8bqrp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/ModalWrapper.js:0-885)

Listitem.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ModalWrapper from "./ModalWrapper";

const ListItem = ({ photo }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div key={photo.id} className="grid__item card">
          <div className="card__body">
            <Link to={{ pathname: `/${photo.id}`, state: photo }}>
              <img src={photo.urls.small} alt="" />
            </Link>
            <Route path="/:photoId" component={ModalWrapper} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};
export default ListItem;
```

ModalWrapper.js

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const customStyles = {
  content: {
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    right: "auto",
    bottom: "auto",
    marginRight: "-50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
  }
};

Modal.setAppElement("#root");

function ModalWrapper() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  const photo = location.state;

  function downloadImage() {}

  function close() {
    history.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={true} onRequestClose={close} style={customStyles}>
      <img src={photo.urls.small} alt="" />

      <div>
        <button onClick={close} className="button">
          Close
        </button>
        <button onClick={downloadImage()}>Download</button>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default ModalWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that `useLocation()` of "react-router-dom" module does not have any state when you first land on the page.

Maybe you have to first set it with the data from `https://api.unsplash.com/photos${window.location.pathname}?client_id=your_clt_id` and after that you can open the modal with the photo.urls.small

So you have to fill your application state before the modal is opened, I guess.

Anyway the error says

> ```
> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
>      in App (at src/index.js:9)
>      in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
> ```

But I don't think that is a memory leak but rater, as I said above, that you are opening the modal before the app is loaded propery (ie the states filled)

UPDATE

Maybe a possible solution is to make a singleton of your App component and then use that singleton instance for retriving the photo in the instance.state.photos, instead of picking the location.state.

Anyway I don't like singletons, and I don't like React neither! It seems quite overkill for an app like yours, IMHO.

I also decided to explore codesandbox, and I found that you can fork it on github. Wow!
So I made a repo on my github in order to better explain what I'm talking about!

I think that this commit is clear enough

[image: I removed the repo sorry]

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-rain-8bqrp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/ListItem.js this is the sandbox where I'm working. I've come across url query that works or persists even after refreshes but not sure how to use it here. can you shed some light on it?

Comment: you app works when you have a state setted, ie if you build your app in local, from the home page you click a photo and then refresh the page, but if you copy paste the url of a img in a private window, then you get the error